# Java - Logging Into Facebook

Tags: java

I have a URL that I need to go to in my Java application and then get the source code of the page. The problem is that you need to be authorized on Facebook to access the page.

Is it possible to go into a web browser, log-in to Facebook then somehow run my application and have access to the page?

Or do I need to log into Facebook through my application? How do I do that? I have tried using this: code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/ but I can't find any basic tutorials for noobs on how to set this up and most are outdated so please don't link me to anything.

I'd prefer to use only the official API if that's possible...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following code and [this page](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) should help you to log into your facebook with Java:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.facebook.com"); 
final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("login_form");  
final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputsByValue("Log in"); 
final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("email");
textField.setValueAttribute("youremailaddress@domain.com"); 
final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("pass");      
textField.setValueAttribute("yourPassword"); 
final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```